# CakePHP 4 - How to change property - fields mapping in entities?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, entity

Fields are exposed to properties automatically, but I want to overwrite this. Is it possible? If so how?

This is what I have:
Table: users

- id
- mail
- user_firstname

This is what I want to have:
Entity: User

- $id
- $email (will be mapped to mail)
- $first_name (will be mapped to user_firstname)

Please note that I want to do this because it is a legacy DB that we can't modify until the codebase is completely updated.

Answer (score 1):

In entity class add

```
protected function _getFirstName()
{
    return $this->user_firstname;
}
```

in views:

```
echo $user->first_name;
```

Read more:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

Comment: This is what I thought, but will `$user->user_firstname` be still accessible?

Comment: Yes. This adds a new virtual property, it doesn't change anything at all about the existing one.

Comment: Make sure to use [IdeHelper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper) or manually set the read only property annotations on the entity class to make it easier for your IDE to understand those.